VIdeo player that support bookmark for certain timestamp
I need video player that able to flag certain timestamps with comment. Adding comment/description is preferred via GUI for better user experience instead of separate TXT.
Moreover I would able to see the overview of bookmarks that have been added.
For example

01:12:00 -> He left the house


01:22:00 -> He found camp site

and so on.
Besides, I need video playback for certain speedup. VLC media player is limited to 1.5X.
The OS I prefer is Windows, about pricing, it's optional whether the software is free or priced.

The statement about VLC is invalid - here e.g. I'm playing a video on 6.6x: https://i.imgur.com/bWZR2qa.png Only menu shows few options, there's a lot more freedom. Anyways, what are the comments exactly? Chapters, like in YT? Or just some comments saved in separate text file?

@Destroy666 What I mean with comments is chapter like YT, comments, bookmark, flag, chapter, mark, I would consider same.

Via GUI is preferred, I can see live frame what's going on compared to open notepad to write it. Let the app handling everything, if the app stored what I write on GUI will be written to .txt file, I don't mind. The goal is to find better user experience.

Welcome Muhammad! Do you have an operating system preference and/or a price range preference (or prefer recommendations for gratis software)?  If so, can you please update your question and tags to include that information?  Thanks, and again, welcome!
